# Validating the ROA certificate

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, x.509, validation

Suppose I have a system, where the server requires the clients to attach their ROA certificate to prove that they have the right to that IP Prefix.

Now if the client attaches the ROA certificate ( which has an extension of .roa ) , I am able to pretty print it using rcynic.

When I print it , there are different fields for validity, IP prefix , public key, etc.  N

I have come across the RPKI protocol where the ROA's are cached in the router's database and is constantly updated. But I want to know weather I can assume that If a client posseses a ROA certificate, it is valid(after confirming the fields of validity)? Or is there a way to verify that the certificate is valid.

Comment: you need to validate with the trust anchors

Comment: @schroederthank you so much. If you put this as an answer. I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key factors (pardon the pun) of RPKI is the network of '[trust anchors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_anchor)' (think CAs) that validate the ROA certificates. You need to check with them to see if the submitted ROA is valid.

Comment: So one of the fields in the ROA file is the public key and there is a field for the URI which points to an object which is stored in a trusted entity. When I went to the URI, and obtained the object, and compared its public key with the public key of the ROA, they were the same. Is it a good validation?